# Windows 7 games file location

Tags: windows-7

On Windows XP, the FreeCell executable was located in the `X:\WINDOWS\System32\` folder, named `freecell.exe`. Where can I find the game files in the case of Windows 7, provided that the game is playable on the current Windows 7 installation and is visible through the Games Explorer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Freecell, Hearts, etc. are located in the appropriate subfolders under `X:\Program Files\Microsoft Games\` (although I've heard others say they're still in System32).  Note that these are special executables with .mui companion files, and won't work on earlier versions of Windows.

Comment: thanks :) I didn't know about the .mui files. I guess that playing that with WINE is not an option then...

Answer (score 3):

It's located at:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games\FreeCell\